# Compass Phonegap undefined

Tags: cordova

I have a big problem with compass plugin on phonegap 3.1,

This is a part of my js code:

```
var compass = {
    inicialize:function(){
        var options = {
            frequency: 3000
        };
        var watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(compass.showInformation, function(err){console.log('Error',err)},options);
    },

    showInformation:function(heading){
        alert('Heading',heading.magneticHeading);
        console.log('Show Heading',heading);
        $('#compass').html(heading.magneticHeading);
    }
}
```

I Already added the plugin on config.xml:

> 

I run adb logcat and this is my log:

```
D/CordovaWebView( 1209): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
I/Process (   80): Sending signal. PID: 1209 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/JsMessageQueue( 1209): Set native->JS mode to 2
I/Process (   80): Sending signal. PID: 1209 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm( 1209): GC_CONCURRENT freed 291K, 3% free 13533K/13895K, paused 10ms+
11ms
I/Process (   80): Sending signal. PID: 1209 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1209): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/webviewglue( 1209): nativeDestroy view: 0x1d4df0
I/ActivityManager(   80): Displayed com.coinding.mobile/.Coinding: +1s978ms
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   80): setKernelCountSet(10025, 0) failed with
errno -2
**E/Web Console( 1209): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'watchHeading' of** u
ndefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers/compass.js:6
I/Web Console( 1209): Geolocalization at file:///android_asset/www/js/init.js:25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the Compass plugin hasn't been added.

To add the plugin, in your root Cordova project directory, run:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-orientation
```

This will fix the errors about `navigator.compass` being undefined, by generating the appropriate files in your directory, but you will still have to add the appropriate permissions to allow this functionality to work.

Please see the documentation for more detail:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_compass_compass.md.html#Compass
A word of advice, each time you load the Cordova online documentation, before reading the page, check the version in the upper right corner.

Comment: HI LonelyCoder, thanks for your answer, I added the plugin and all works fine. Thanks